# How to get value from Drop Down box?

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I have a problem with pulling data out of a list. Here is how I fill the dropdown:

```
public void fillData() {
    cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllEmail();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    EMAILS = new String[] { DbAdapter.KEY_EMAIL };
    textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.emailText);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, EMAILS);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);       
}
```

and now I'm trying to pull in the value when a button is pressed but don't really know what to pass:

```
        collectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int message = textView.getId();
             //value of drop down here.
        }
```

I've spend 4 hours on this problem now, need some help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want selected item try this:

```
textView.getListSelection()
```

it returns the position of the current selection ([doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#getListSelection%28%29))

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
collectButton.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){ 
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    Cursor cursor = (Cursor)_yourMainCursor.getItem(position)
  }  
});
```

Note that I am using onItemClick and not onClickListener. A difference big enough.
Essentially it does the same, it reacts on a click, however onItemClick responds on one item in a list kind of view, be it listview, autocomplete or spinner